# What is the difference between past anterior and pluperfect when translated in English?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, comparaison-de-langues

Could anyone explain with simple examples the difference between "past anterior" (Le passé antérieur) and "pluperfect of the indicative" (le plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif)? The only difference I know is the formation of the tenses. I would especially like to know the difference when one translates a sentence from French to English.

Are they both translated as "had done something"? Or is there any other nuance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference in meaning. The [passé antérieur](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/past-anterior/) is the literary equivalent of the [plus-que-parfait](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/past-perfect/).

They're used in exactly the same constructions (e.g., after *après que*) but the plus-que-parfait is "normal" - used in spoken French and informal writing, while the passé antérieur is literary: limited to literature and other formal writing.